# Split по regexp: разбить строку по неэкранированому пробелу

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть строка типа `str = 'val1 val2 va\\ 3 val\\ 4'`. Надо получить массив

```
var arr = [
  'val1',
  'val2',
  'va\\ 3',
  'val\\ 4'
]
```

Другими словами, разбить строку по неэкранированому пробелу. Знаю, что `String.prototype.split` поддерживает RegExp в качестве аргумента, но в связи с тем, что javascript не поддерживает просмотр назад, это мне мало чего дает. Пробовал так `str.split(/[^\\]\s/);`, но отсекается последний символ. Как можно решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут match нужен

```
splittedString=str.match(/(?:\\\s|[^\s\n])(?:(?:[^\s\n]|\\\s)*?(?:[^\\](?=\s)|\\(?=$|\n)))?(?=[\s]|$)/g);
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ItksrR7ZeA1azaXW)

Comment: @Deonis, способ имитировать просмотр назад в javascript? Спасибо, в будущем, возможно, пригодится.

Comment: `Array [ "1lav", "2lav", "3 \av", "4 \lav" ]` это кажется не то что хотел @alvoro

Comment: @eicto, подходит. Спасибо.

Comment: @eicto, угу. Поспешил, не проверив. Забыл, что в конце переворачиваю массив в целом, а не каждый из элементов.

----------

Всё же доведу до конца, хоть способ и не эффективный:

    var str = 'val1 val2 va\\ 3 val\\ 4',
        res = [];
    String.prototype.reverse = function () {
        return this.split('').reverse().join('');
    };
    str.reverse().split(/\s(?!\\)/).reverse()
        .forEach(function(el, i){
        res[i] = el.reverse();
    });
    console.log(res);

Comment: А вот если бы вы не извращались с прототипом, то в forEach можно было-бы написать просто forEach(stringReverse).

Comment: @eicto, в Вашем решении баг:

    'val1 val2 va\\ 3 val\\  4'.match(/[^ ].*?[^\\](?= |$)/g);
    //Выводит:
    [ 'val1',
      'val2',
      'va\\ 3',
      'val\\ ' ]

Если перед `4` поставить пробел, то она не попадает в результирующий массив.

Comment: Ага, вижу, там два символа мин на элемент... попробую придумать, чего с этим сделать.

Исправил.

Comment: @eicto, еще раз спасибо. Я решил делать на циклах, но если вам еще интересно, то вот один баг:

    'val1 val2 va\\ 3 val\\'.match(/(?:\\\s|[^\s\n])(?:(?:[^\s\n]|\\\s)*?[^\\])?(?=[\s\n]|$)/g);

Comment: Это тоже fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Можно и split, только телодвижений больше:

```
var str = 'val1 val2 va\\ 3 val\\ 4';
String.prototype.reverse = function () {
    return this.split('').reverse().join('');
};
console.log( str.reverse().split(/\s(?!\\)/).reverse() );
```

Comment: Fix:  

    /\s(?!\\(?:\\\\)*)/
Вроде как-то так, чтобы экранированные слэши исключить.